# Evaluating the precision in the calculation of $\mathrm{e}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, exponential-function, approximation

I'm calculating $\mathrm{e}$ using a computer like this:
$$
\mathrm{e} \approx \sum\limits_{i=0}^n {1\over i!}
$$
I'm storing it as a rational number.

I was wondering, if I write down my rational number as a decimal number, could I determine, 
how many digits after the decimal point are correct for a given value of $n$?

Comment: You need $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty$, starting with $i=0$, not with $i=1$, and going to $\infty$, not to $n$.  Also, the fraction should be $\dfrac{1}{i!}$, not $\dfrac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think the $n$ on top is what the OP wants. He should have written $\approx$ instead of $=$.

Comment: @GitGud : If so, then it should not say "$=$". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Unrelated but potentially useful to the OP: using the continued fraction expansion for $\exp(z)$ is more accurate, and if you compute the convergents $A_{n}$, $B_{n}$ recursively...it is faster since it uses fewer division operations...

Comment: @AlexNelson: This formula (implemented correctly) will take only $n-1$ division operations. What continued fraction expansion do you have in mind that takes fewer?

Comment: I just fixed a pretty confusing typo in my answer, and then did a notational simplification.  If it didn't do anything for you before, try again now.

Comment: "I'm storing it as a rational number" - do you really mean a rational, as in a data type that explicitly stores numerator and denominator with no rounding error, or do you mean a floating-point datatype, probably called something like `float` or `double`, which has limited precision and introduces rounding error?

Comment: @user21820 Well, look at (e.g.) Wikipedia's [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction) for the general formulas for the numerator and denominator. You can compute them recursively, requiring (for each iteration) 2 additions and 4 multiplications. So $N$ iterations costs 1 division operation (the final division) + $2N$ addition + $4N$ multiplication, far better than the naive Taylor series.

Comment: @AlexNelson: As I said, the Taylor series takes only $n-1$ division operations, each of which is by a number that has length $O(\log(n))$, so even the naive division (in base 2) takes $O(n\log(n))$ time. And to repeat my question, what continued fraction expansion do you have in mind that **gives the same accuracy as the $n$-th Taylor series approximate** and takes asymptotically less than $O(n\log(n))$ time, or even merely asymptotically less than $O(n)$ division operations?

Comment: @user21820 A division operation is costlier than a multiplication operation. (About 5 times costlier, in fact, for x86 floating point...and rational arithmetic would be worse, computing the gcd and then performing 2 division operations...) The continued fraction expansion any sane person would have in mind [could be googled in a second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Continued_fractions_for_ex). Remember $e=\exp(1)$...

Comment: @AlexNelson: If you're only talking about x86 floating point, there's little point in arguing, because the difference will only be a matter of constant factors, and I don't really care about that. I was talking about arbitrary precision, as I made clear when I counted in the length of the input. So when you claimed that there is a continued fraction that is faster to compute, I thought you meant asymptotically faster.

Comment: Furthermore, the two continued fractions on that Wikipedia page are not suitable for computing $e^x$ to arbitrary precision for all $x$. Rather, some basic identity needs to be used first, before either a Taylor expansion or the continued fraction is used, in order to guarantee $O(\sqrt{n}M(n))$ time complexity where $M(n)$ is the time complexity for a single multiplication of numbers of length $n$. In practice the Taylor expansion is always used, and if you only want to obtain $e$ to fixed precision (of say 64 bits) you are of course better of precomputing and storing it as a constant.

Comment: @user21820 err, you seem to be forgetting the topic of discussion is computing $e$ to some desired precision. (I am not worried about $\exp(x)$ for general $x$, just $x=1$.) The 20th continuant of the continued fraction cited is good beyond 100 digits, requires 40 addition operations, 80 multiplication ops, and 1 division op. The Taylor series, OTOH, requires 38 terms, in Horner form that's 38 multiplication ops + 38 addition ops + the killer 38 division ops. That number of division operations makes it **practically** unacceptable...

Comment: @AlexNelson: You are the one who doesn't understand arbitrary precision, **which of course means computing to some arbitrary desired precision**, nor do you understand the algorithms used to do so. Neither do you seem to understand that the Taylor series only requires division by $O(\log(n))$-digit numbers, which takes only $O(n\log(n))$ time even with naive division, and so the resulting naive algorithm will take $O(n^2\log(n))$ time in total, which is in fact better than using the continued fraction, which requires a total of $O(nM(n))$ time.

Comment: Furthermore, if you actually understood what I said earlier, you will know that you get $O(\sqrt{n}M(n))$ time complexity using the Taylor series. This identity is indeed necessary even for $e^1$, otherwise you cannot get this time complexity. And please go and check for yourself that division requires exactly the same time complexity as multiplication, which is why there is little difference whether either is used, **unless you are talking about x86 architecture, in which case you are limited to fixed-precision already and might as well store $e$ as a constant**.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake two comments up; using the continued fraction recurrence requires $O(n^2\log(n))$ time, so there's no difference from the naive method using the Taylor series. By the way, the fastest way currently known is neither of the above methods, but it is to use the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean iteration to compute $\log$ and Newton-Raphson to compute its inverse.

Comment: @user21820 I think there is some ambiguity surrounding the term "arbitrary precision arithmetic". Since the OP was interested in having a rational approximation good to $n$ digits, I assumed the OP would be using something like MIT-Scheme which has "Bignum" arbitrary precision rationals. (Hence my concern about the number of division operations: they are the most costly for `Bignum` arithmetic.) Your use of the phrase "arbitrary precision" seems non-technical...but we have gone far from the ranch, and it seems completely irrelevant to the OP.

Comment: No actually my use of "arbitrary precision arithmetic" is the standard one, and you can check my claims at various places such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations. Perhaps you can say that I'm not interested in constant factors, which may have been what you were concerned about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the Taylor remainder formula you get that, for some $\xi\in (0,1)$
$$
0<\mathrm{e}-\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{\mathrm{e}^\xi}{(n+1)!}<\frac{3}{(n+1)!}.
$$
Thus the error is less than $\frac{3}{(n+1)!}$.

Comment: This is definitely not the simplest way.  It relies, for example, on the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 10):

As yet another possibility, if you calculate
$$\frac1e = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} $$
then you have an *alternating series*, so the true value of $1/e$ is strictly between any two successive partial sums, which you can then invert and represent in decimal. Any digits they agree on are certain.

Answer (score 5):

The tail of the series is bounded above by a geometric series:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i!} \le \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^i}.
\end{align}

It's easy to find the sum of that series, so you get an upper bound on $e$.

The *lower* bound comes from stopping after finitely many terms.

Answer (score 4):

Since the factorials grow so fast, the first term you ignore is a very good estimate for the error.  So if you sum up through $n=10$, the first ignored term is $\frac 1{11!}\approx 2.5\cdot 10^{-8}$  The next is a factor $12$ smaller, so using the first as your error estimate is pretty good.